# dependence structure in GAM partial residual plot {mgcv}

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I am modeling daily mortality (dependent variable) against lag 1-day mean temperature (independent variable) with GAM, using the {mgcv} package in R.

While looking through my data I noticed some of my models showed a dependent structure in their partial residual plot:

```
gam <- gam(mortality ~ s(l1meantemp, bs = "cr", k = 10), family = poisson(link = log), data = data) 

plot.gam(gam, residuals = TRUE)
```

[image]

I don't think the problem is related to overdispersion, or the wrong specification of k, the number of knots. I checked overdispersion using the negative binomial distribution,

```
gam_nb <- gam(mortality ~ s(l1meantemp, bs = "cr", k = 10), family = nb(link = log), data = data) 
summary(gam_nb)
```

which gave me an overdispersion paramter $\theta$ = 108.475, (assuming $Y \sim negbin$, $var(Y) = \mu (1 + \mu/\theta)$, and as $\theta \rightarrow \infty$, we get poisson) which I think is large enough to assume poisson distribution. 
Also I checked the number of knots k = 10 was sufficient, using

```
gam.check(gam)
```

.

My guess now is that I probably did not include all of the necessary variables needed to explain daily mortality, but I'm not sure. Why would this kind of pattern appear in a partial residuals plot? What are some of your suggestions to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have repeated measures of any kind, e.g., something that could be considered individual subjects or groups that have been measured repeatedly? Then you need to include a random effects smoother. Also, since you have daily data, you should include time in your model in some way (because you almost certainly will have auto-correlation). It could be as simple as a smoother for time or it could be as an auto-correlation structure via the `gamm` function. This depends on your data and what you want to know from the model / do with the model.

Comment: @Roland Thanks for your answer. I think you are right. Adding some smoother for time definitely seems to lessen auto-correlation.